# "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, google-play

"You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher."

My Client is getting this error while uploading my App on Play Store. I have resolved the issue on on my side. but how Can I test this on Android Studio. As I was not getting the error earlier as well? (How I solved this ? I defined android:exported Property in Manifest.xml).

Complied SDK : 31
minSDK : 19

Answer (score 0):

It's a change in Android as of 12.  Exported used to have a default.  For greater security it no longer has a default and you must specify the value. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test it on the emulator. Install an emulator with 31 SDK
[create emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)

It helps you check your fix

Comment: I am using React-native for this app. Is there any way I can test this on a physical device?

Comment: You need a device with android 12